# How to compute connected components in OrientDB

Tags: orientdb, gremlin

Does OrientDB's support efficient computations of [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory))?

I am not experienced with graph databases. My naiive intuition is that this operation should be quite efficient.

If it is efficiently supported, how would a query look like to find all connected components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had your same issue but I finally ended up writing an OSQL query to compute connected components in a graph, here is [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33654067/orientdb-connected-components-osql-query)

Answer (score -1):

Below is an excerpt from the [OrientDB website](http://orientdb.com/why-orientdb/). I've highlighted a few relevant portions.

> OrientDB can embed documents like any other document database, but
>   also supports relationships. It doesn’t use the costly JOIN. Instead,
>   **OrientDB uses super-fast, persistent pointers between records**, taken
>   from the graph database world. You can traverse parts of or entire
>   trees and graphs of records in just a few milliseconds.
>
> This illustration shows how the original document has been
>   split into two documents linked using the Customer’s Record ID #8:124
>   to connect the Order to the Customer document. Links can be thought of
>   as in-memory pointers, but persistent on disk.
>
> [snip]
>
> Equipped With document and relational DBMS, the more data you
>   have, the slower the database will be. Joins have a heavy runtime
>   cost. Instead, OrientDB handles relationships as physical links to the
>   records, assigned only once, when the edge is created O(1). Compare
>   this to an RDBMS that “computes“ the relationship every single time
>   you query a database O(LogN). **With OrientDB, traversing speed is not
>   affected by the database size. It is always constant, whether for one
>   record or 100 billion records.** This is critical in the age of Big
>   Data!

And here is an example query taken from the [tutorial document](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Tutorial-Working-with-graphs.html), which will get all the friends of the person called Luca.

`SELECT EXPAND( BOTH( 'Friend' ) ) FROM Person WHERE name = 'Luca'`